# How to parse CSV file with empty values in Octave?

Tags: matlab, csv, octave

I have the following CSV data that I am trying to parse in Octave. Note that the values in the last column are empty:

```
102,19700101,,0.485,
111,19700101,,0.48,
```

I have defined my line format as:

```
lineFormat = [repmat('%s',1,1), ...
         repmat('%f',1,1), ...
         repmat('%q',1,1), ...
         repmat('%f',1,1), ...
         repmat('%q',1,1)];
```

How can I read this in with `textscan`? When I try:

```
C = textscan(fid, lineFormat, 'Delimiter', ',')
```

I incorrectly get the following (notice that the second line from the CSV is shifted):

```
C = 
{
  [1,1] = 
  {
    [1,1] = 102
    [2,1] = 19700101
  }
  [1,2] =

     1.9700e+07
            NaN

  [1,3] = 
  {
    [1,1] = 
    [2,1] = 0.48
  }
  [1,4] =

       0.48500
     110.00000

  [1,5] = 
  {
    [1,1] = 111
    [2,1] = 19700101
  }
}
```

I've also tried with `'MultipleDelimsAsOne'` but the last column value is still omitted. How do I read my CSV data in properly with `textscan`? This code works as expected in MATLAB, but not in Octave.

Running Octave 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Use the `csv2cell` function from the `io` package. It is a lot more useful than the generic csvread function. Having said this, you could have easily used a standard csvread in this case too, no need for a complicated textscan at all ...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I believe I need `textscan`, as the values in the last column can be strings. I will investigate `csv2cell`, however.

Comment: Yes, do. `csv2cell` can handle any content and is hassle free compared to textscan etc. Well worth keeping in mind. (I love your profile pic btw!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a bug in Octave: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57612

I got around this by adding an extra comma to the end of my CSV files whose lines ended in a comma. Since Octave ignores the final comma, adding a second comma causes Octave to not ignore the second-to-last one:

```
102,19700101,,0.485,,
111,19700101,,0.48,,
```

Here's a shell one-liner to fix all the CSV files in a directory:

```
find ${1:-.} -type f -name *.csv -exec sed -i -e 's/,$/,,/g' {} \;
```

This is not a great solution, just a work-around for the existing bug.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, setting the [`EndOfLine`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/textscan.html) parameter helped for me (Windows 10, Octave 5.1.0):

```matlab
C = textscan(fid, lineFormat, 'Delimiter', ',', 'EndOfLine', '\n')
```

The output seems correct:

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 102
    [2,1] = 111
  }
  [1,2] =
     19700101
     19700101
  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
  }
  [1,4] =
     0.48500
     0.48000
  [1,5] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to test your `%q` columns and expanded your example:

```
102,19700101,,0.485,
111,19700101,,0.48,
111,19700101,,0.48,"test"
111,19700101,"test",0.48,
```

Unfortunately, the above solution doesn't work properly here:

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 102
    [2,1] = 111
    [3,1] = 111
    [4,1] =
  }
  [1,2] =

     19700101
     19700101
     19700101
          111
  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
    [3,1] =
    [4,1] = 19700101
  }
  [1,4] =

     0.48500
     0.48000
     0.48000
  [1,5] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
    [3,1] = test
  }
}
```

But, when switching from `%q` to `%s` in `lineformat`, it works as expected:

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 102
    [2,1] = 111
    [3,1] = 111
    [4,1] = 111
  }
  [1,2] =

     19700101
     19700101
     19700101
     19700101
  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
    [3,1] =
    [4,1] = "test"
  }
  [1,4] =
     0.48500
     0.48000
     0.48000
     0.48000
  [1,5] =
  {
    [1,1] =
    [2,1] =
    [3,1] = "test"
    [4,1] =
  }
}
```

I have no explanation for that; a bug maybe? If you can live with removing the double quotes yourself afterwards, this (still) might a solution for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this didn't fix my issue. I'm running Octave 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, added that information to the question. What's worked temporarily is adding a space character to the last column in the CSV so that it is not empty, but that's not a great solution.

Comment: I also opened this bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57612